# save data in nested forloop in c#

Tags: c#, for-loop, datatables

below is my code

```
string Cmp_Cd_Typ_Id1_1 = "";
for (a = 0; a < dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Columns.Count; a++)
{
    for (b = 0; b < dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Columns.Count; b++)
    {
        Cmp_Cd_Typ_Id1_1 = Cmp_Cd_Typ_Id1_1 + dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Rows[a][b].ToString() + ",";
    }
}
```

am saving data in Cmp_Cd_Typ_Id1_1 variable. I need to save data of each iteration separately but here I get result as a,b,c,d. but I need to save a separately b separately etc. How can I achieve this

Comment: Whats the content of the `DataTable`? You can save the variables in a `List`.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A string variable can hold a single string, not multiple strings. If you want to extract multiple strings use a List. If you describe your *actual* problem it will be easier to help. Are you trying to extract each row as a comma-separated string? Are you trying to create a CSV file? Did you want to retrieve the values of a specific column?

Comment: use string array instead of string variable like string[] Cmp_Cd_Typ_Id1_1 =new string[] ;
int i=0;
  for (a = 0; a < dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Columns.Count; a++)
                            {
                                for (b = 0; b < dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Columns.Count; b++)
                                {
                                    Cmp_Cd_Typ_Id1_1[i] =  dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Rows[a][b].ToString() ;
     i++;
 
                                }

                            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexer `a` should be applied to the Rows collection, not to the Columns collection

```
for (a = 0; a < dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; a++)
```

Also is strongly recommended to use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Text.StringBuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a string concatenation like that

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (int a = 0; a < dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Columns.Count; b++)
    {
        result.Append(dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Rows[a][b].ToString() + ",");
    }
}
string Cmp_Cd_Typ_Id1_1 = result.ToString();
```

Instead, if you want the rows separated from each other, then you need to add at this approach a `List<strings>`

```
// Each row will be an element of this list
List<string> rows = new List<string>();

for (int a = 0; a < dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Rows.Count; a++)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int b = 0; b < dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Columns.Count; b++)
    {
        result.Append(dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Rows[a][b].ToString() + ",");
    }
    // Add the row to the list removing the last comma
    rows.Add(result.ToString(0, result_1.Length - 1); 
}
```

Comment: String.Join on Rows would work just as well and result in cleaner code

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating the values on the same string, you could use an string array or a list to store values, for example:

```
List<string> Cmp_Cd_Typ_Id1_1 = new List<string>;
for (a = 0; a < dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Columns.Count; a++)
{
    for (b = 0; b < dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Columns.Count; b++)
    {
        Cmp_Cd_Typ_Id1_1.Add(dsDeviceMatch2.Tables[0].Rows[a][b].ToString());
    }
}
```